# Monitoring website using sakuli , on each server in a cluster

Tags: selenium

There is a Title of the website we are testing for example :

```
<div class=titleTitle">TitleOfTheWebsite"</div>
```

Is it possible to check for each server in the cluster individually .We are currently using sakuli version 2.5.0

My boss is providing this solution but I am not sure if this is even possible:
The routing to the individual instances is done via a cookie on the respective domain, in the form key: ROUTEID, value: .rx1 to .rx3. If such a thing can't be set with Sakuli itself, there seems to be a fallback to Selenium that should do it: https://sakuli.io/docs/writing_tests/webtests/#selenium-fallbacks and then

```
driver.manage().addCookie("ROUTEID", ".rx1");
```

Please provide your suggestions

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is the given problem related to Typescript or Docker?

Comment: There is no tag called sakuli , hence the other tags. I know that the title of the website can be monitored. But can it be monitored for individual server in a cluster.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If your problem is not related to Docker or Typescript, please remove these tags